# star rating in bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way to add star rating in bootstrap popover?

I tried doing this But I am not getting the Count -

Code -

```
$('#member1').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: function() {
        return $($(this).data('contentwrapper')).html();
    }
}).click(function() {
    $('.star').each(function(el) {
      $(this).raty('destroy');
        $(this).raty({

            starOff : 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/images/star-off.png',
            starOn : 'http://wbotelhos.com/raty/lib/images/star-on.png',
            start: $(this).attr('data-rating')
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9WhH/3/

Is there any better solution?

I want result like this -

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot associate your example image with the fiddle? But,think the row / col markup somehow ruins the popover, why not just

```html
<div class="contentEval">
   <div class="ratings star" id="rating1" data-rating="1"></div>
</div>
```

Then, see the raty docs -> http://wbotelhos.com/raty/ you need to create an event where you can transfer the selected rating back to the `data-range` attribute :

```js
..
click: function(score, evt) {
  $('#member1').popover('hide');                   
  $(this).attr('data-rating', score);
  alert('your rating is : '+$('.star').attr('data-rating'));
}
..
```

see forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4C5W6/**